# Box-api development interface in the application pages

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

I have a Box.net (.com) account and wanted to create an application in Box. 
I looked around the admin pages but can't find it.
I know it is possible, but I can't find it in the Administrative application pages. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "development interface" for Box is not in the administrative pages. You have to create a separate account for development. IMHO this is limiting, since most likely companies will have development teams and they should be linked to the Admin account, but I understand that separating them brings more flexibility.

But I digress. The admin pages are reached through https://box.com, but the development pages are in https://developers.box.com/

Comment: That's right.  Not every developer should be an admin, and not every admin should be a developer...